# How to query hourly aggregated data by date with postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

There is one table:

```
ID DATE 
1  2017-09-16 20:12:48
2  2017-09-16 20:38:54
3  2017-09-16 23:58:01
4  2017-09-17 00:24:48
5  2017-09-17 00:26:42
..
```

The result I need is the last 7-days of data with hourly aggregated count of rows:

```
COUNT DATE
2     2017-09-16 21:00:00
0     2017-09-16 22:00:00
0     2017-09-16 23:00:00
1     2017-09-17 00:00:00
2     2017-09-17 01:00:00
..
```

I tried different stuff with EXTRACT, DISTINCT and also used the generate_series function (most stuff from similar stackoverflow questions)

This try was the best one currently:

```
SELECT 
  date_trunc('hour', demotime) as date,
  COUNT(demotime) as count
FROM demo
GROUP BY date
```

How to generate hourly series for 7 days and fill-in the count of rows?

Comment: what is the problem with your "best" query?

Comment: That I don't know how to generate series for 7 days, it's just everything or with an limit limitated, but I need exactly a result of 7(days)*24(hours) rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**SQL DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ecbf7/8)

```
SELECT dd, count("demotime")     
FROM generate_series
        ( current_date - interval '7 days'
        , current_date 
        , '1 hour'::interval) dd
LEFT JOIN Table1        
  ON dd = date_trunc('hour', demotime)        
GROUP BY dd;
```

To work from now and now - 7 days:

```
SELECT dd, count("demotime")     
FROM generate_series
        ( date_trunc('hour', NOW()) - interval '7 days'
        , date_trunc('hour', NOW())
        , '1 hour'::interval) dd
LEFT JOIN Table1        
  ON dd = date_trunc('hour', demotime)        
GROUP BY dd;
```

Comment: Works well, thank you!
is there any function to get the current date to replace the fixed date-stuff with now() and now()-7days?

Comment: Of course, you should ask that in the question I tought you need a speciific range. Check edit   ... Sory I read again ... didnt saw the **last 7 days**  .. but in my defense your data were much older than last week

Comment: Just be carefull `current_date` is `00:00` of today. So you wont get any hour from today.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear enough, anyways thank you - works great.

Comment: isn't now() then a better option instead of the second current_date (due to the 00:00 problem)

Comment: Yes, you can use `now()` instead of `current_date` ... I just use date because we where talking about days ;)

Comment: It seems like "now() - interval '7 days' " won't work, now I got your point - the correct phrase from my side should be: "the last 7 days from now"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158698/discussion-between-simlet-and-juan-carlos-oropeza).